# Change DIV based on server response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webform(popup) that 
has a field which I can insert an email
address and i can get it into the database.
I was thinking if its possible to get a response from 
the database/server for exemple a variable or a string, which 
I could use it for modify the innerhtml of my popup.

Something like:

if i get this string, change the innerhtmlofthis div.

I think ajax does that some how.

```
        <script>
         if (logic)
        $('"value_string_from_server"').load('Popup_response.html'); }); 
       </script>
```

Can I for exemple use this to

```
            string MyUrl = "http://testurl?
            MyUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(MyUrl);
```

and then check if the variable is equal to the string url I specify, then change the DIV?

Comment: you can use **.load()** jquery api for loading html. Basic syntax is `$('Target_Selector').load('Popup_response.html')`. Are you getting any problem using **load** ?

Comment: selector is not correct

Comment: the target selector would be the DIV I want to change and the Popup_response.html would be the external html page that i want to load into the div. But how to implement this on condition depending on the URL (that i get a a response back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your popup html will have div tags . Identify your parent div tag id of your popup window

let say your popup is having content with form.

After getting response you can use following javascript

jQuery("#popup").html(YOURRESPONSE);

Comment: Yes, the popup has DIV tags. So  "#popup" should be the name of the parent DIV i want to change the content and YOURRESPONSE for istance can be an URL for exemple: https://www.exemple.com/?status=mailalreadysubmitted ??